# Do i need to Dispose?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlconnection

I have an application and some of the code is written like the example.
Is the Connection.Dispose needed? Would it be causing any problems?
Thanks!

```
        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCONSTRING").ConnectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select TextData from Table1 where key = 1", Connection)
            Connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Try
                While reader.Read()

                    Dim T1 As String = reader("TextData").ToString()

                End While
            Finally
                reader.Close()
            End Try
            Connection.Close()
            Connection.Dispose()
        End Using
```

UPDATED:

```
        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCONSTRING").ConnectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select TextData from Table1 where key = 1", Connection)
            Connection.Open()
            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim T1 As String = reader("TextData").ToString()
                 End While
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Your Connection object is declared with an `Using` statement, so no, you don't need to either call `Close()` or `Dispose()`, since it's already done -- You should do the same thing with the DataReader, an `Using` statement is a Try/Finally block under the hood

Comment: Using does the same as `Try
   ' Insert code to work with resource.
Finally
    If resource IsNot Nothing Then
        resource.Dispose()
    End If
End Try` and `Dispose()` calls `Close()` in this case. See: [Using Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have posted updated version. does this look better?

Comment: @user3841736 - Every object that you create (and control the lifetime of) must have `.Dispose()` called, either explicitly or through a `using`. Always.

Comment: Updated version look good

Answer (score 4):

As others said: no, you don't need to add `Close` or `Dispose` if you use the `Using`-statement. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) quote:

> A `Using` block behaves like a `Try...Finally` construction in which the
> Try block uses the resources and the Finally block disposes of them.
> Because of this, the Using block guarantees disposal of the resources,
> no matter how you exit the block. This is true even in the case of an
> unhandled exception

So you should use this:

```
Dim T1 As String = Nothing
Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCONSTRING").ConnectionString)
    Using Command As New SqlCommand("Select TextData from Table1 where key = 1", Connection)
        Connection.Open()
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                T1 = reader("TextData").ToString()
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

In general: use the `Using` statement for everything that implements `IDisposable`.

By the way, since you only select a single value you could also use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

```
Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCONSTRING").ConnectionString)
    Using command As New SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 TextData from Table1 where key = 1", Connection)
        Connection.Open()
        Dim tmp As Object = command.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim T1 As String = If(Convert.IsDBNull(tmp), Nothing, DirectCast(tmp, String))
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I know it isn't needed, but OP did ask whether including `Close()` and `Dispose()` within the `Using` would hurt anything, and I can't find any documentation on that question. My assumption is it is useless but not harmful.

Comment: @MichaelFoster: in theory it can hurt, it depends on the implementation of the `Dispose` method. But it **should not** hurt. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_IDisposable_Dispose): "If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times."